# Ray tracing from different viewpoints

Tags: graphics, 3d, computational-geometry, raytracing

I have a mesh model in obj and obj.mtl files, I want to change the camera viewpoint to a certain coordinate [x,y,z] and then use ray tracing to produce a RGB image and depth map / pointcloud from this viewing angle. Any ideas where to start?

Update: This does not need to be solved in Matlab specifically (removing from title and tag), I have seen libraries such as GLUT and Open Mesa that look like they might be able to do this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the following FEX option:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25383-matlab-mesh-to-pdf-with-3d-interactive-object

Answer (score 0):

Given your question, it seems that you already know how to raytrace for a camera at the origin, and you are wondering how to handle camera motion.

If so, just recall that moving the camera just corresponds to keeping the camera at the origin and moving all the objects in a direction opposite to the motion. More specifically, you need to transform all the objects by the inverse of the camera transformation matrix. And the inverse of a camera transformation matrix just consists in the transpose of the camera orientation, and the opposite of the camera translation.